# What does "was so that" mean?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, optional-that

What does "was so that" mean in the following sentence,

> The reason for coconuts **was so that** we would all have something to
>   eat.  (source: Shadow and the coconut caper written by Richard Hays)

?

Does it mean "The reason for coconuts was so much that we would all have something to eat" or "The reason for coconuts was much so that we would all have something to eat"?

Where did the adjective that should be between 'so' and 'that' disappear?
(be so+adjective+that---> be so that)

Comment: The reason for *what* with coconuts? The issue of *was so that* aside, there's an important semantic component of the sentence that's missing. (Is it explained in the sentences that come before what you quoted?) The sentence essentially means *We (did whatever with) the coconuts (and not with something else) in order to have something to eat.*

Comment: @JasonBassford Is it possible to parse it as : "［The reason for coconuts was so] [that we would all have something to eat. ], where "so" is used as an adverb as In "I think so"?

Comment: @dan No, you've just restated my confusion. The reason for (chopping down / collecting / selling / the existence of) coconuts . . .? It's not about parsing—although I think I rephrased it accurately in my first comment—it's about understanding the missing context.

Comment: @JasonBassford maybe, "that we would all have something to eat" could be "the reason for coconuts"?   Does it make a bit sense?

Comment: @dan Still no. The reason for coconuts to exist? (The universe wants us to eat?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use of "[so](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/so)" is similar to "[therefore](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/therefore)".  In context, it means "to [allow](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/allow)".

This use of "so" is a conjunction, not an adverb.

Comment: If so, what is the difference in the meaning between "The reason for coconuts was so that we would all have something to eat" and "The reason for coconuts was that we would all have something to eat" and "The reason for coconuts was so we would all have something to eat"? Does "the reason for coconuts was so that we would all have something to eat" mean "the reason for coconuts was that we would all have something to eat"?

Comment: @user22046 Yes, they are the same: [_so that_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so_that) is in this case a synonym of _that_, but specifically for giving purpose.